# c# function which has method parameter value, or using delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, delegation

I have two button click events in my window form application.

```
private void butProcess_1_Click(...)
{
    /// below parameters are just sample.
    Process_1(int_param1, decimal_param2, datetime_param3);
}

private void butProcess_2_Click(...)
{
    /// below parameters are just sample.
    Process_2(string_param1, guid_param2, byteArray_param3, bool_param4);
}
```

As those processes take longer time to finish executing, I need to display progress bar to user.
So I modify my event called butProcess_1_Click.

```
private void butProcess_1_Click(...)
{
    frmLoadingControl _frmLoadingControl = new frmLoadingControl();            
    _frmLoadingControl.Show(this);

    BackgroundWorker _BackgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    _BackgroundWorker.DoWork += (s, args) =>
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => this.Enabled = false));
        /// below parameters are just sample.
        Process_1(int_param1, decimal_param2, datetime_param3);
    };
    _BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, args) =>
    {
        _frmLoadingControl.Close();
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => this.Enabled = true));
    };

    _BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

}
```

Everything working correctly.But problem is butProcess_2_Click which I need to copy all code from butProcess_1_Click.
And I have to change only one line to invoke process_2().

```
Process_2(string_param1, guid_param2, byteArray_param3, bool_param4);
```

I don't want to duplicate my code. What I want to do is like below.

```
public void GenericFunction(Function _FunctionCode)
{
    frmLoadingControl _frmLoadingControl = new frmLoadingControl();            
    _frmLoadingControl.Show(this);

    BackgroundWorker _BackgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    _BackgroundWorker.DoWork += (s, args) =>
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => this.Enabled = false));
        /// below parameters are just sample.
        //Process_1(int_param1, decimal_param2, datetime_param3);
        //Process_2(string_param1, guid_param2, byteArray_param3, bool_param4);
        Execute(_FunctionCode);
    };
    _BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, args) =>
    {
        _frmLoadingControl.Close();
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => this.Enabled = true));
    };

    _BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void butProcess_1_Click(...)
{
    /// below parameters are just sample.
    //Process_1(int_param1, decimal_param2, datetime_param3);
    GenericFunction(Process_1(int_param1, decimal_param2, datetime_param3));
}

private void butProcess_2_Click(...)
{
    /// below parameters are just sample.
    //Process_2(string_param1, guid_param2, byteArray_param3, bool_param4);
    GenericFunction(Process_2(string_param1, guid_param2, byteArray_param3, bool_param4));
}
```

Please let me get your suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass a delegate, like this:

```
// CHANGE HERE
public void GenericFunction(Action action)
{
    frmLoadingControl _frmLoadingControl = new frmLoadingControl();            
    _frmLoadingControl.Show(this);

    BackgroundWorker _BackgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    _BackgroundWorker.DoWork += (s, args) =>
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => this.Enabled = false));

        // CHANGE HERE
        action();

        Execute(_FunctionCode);
    };
    _BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, args) =>
    {
        _frmLoadingControl.Close();
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => this.Enabled = true));
    };

    _BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void butProcess_1_Click(...)
{
    // CHANGE HERE
    GenericFunction(() => Process_1(int_param1, decimal_param2, datetime_param3));
}
```

**Shouldn't this**: `_frmLoadingControl.Close();` be put in the `Invoke` in the next row? It is something that "acts" on a "piece" of Winforms...

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => 
{
    _frmLoadingControl.Close();
    this.Enabled = true;
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Action delegate - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx

Background Worker is outdated. Instead, you should use asynchronous methods. - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx